# How to set multiple alarms using same receiver class and same function?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

I am trying to run two alarms to display notifications one is daily and one i hourly in a same receiver class and using the same function but the problem is that when i assign one the other one gets assigned too after i restart my device because of BOOT_COMPLETED,so i want to know is there any way i can achieve this ?

My alarm_receiver class:-

```
public class alarmreceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
   static  int id;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm running", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

           start(context,id);

    }
    static void start(Context context,int id) {
        if (id==1) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, notification_receiver.class);
                PendingIntent pendingintent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                        SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), 60 * 1000
                        , pendingintent);

        } else
            if (id == 2) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, notification_receiver.class);
                PendingIntent pendingintent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 10);
                calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 14);
                calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.PM);
                alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingintent);

            }
    }
    }
```

I am calling this function in my main activity under button click event:-

```
 butn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                if (r1.isChecked()) {

                   alarmreceiver.start(getApplicationContext(),2);

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Daily Affirmations Scheduled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//
                }
                if(r2.isChecked())
                {
                    alarmreceiver.start(getApplicationContext(),1);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hourly Affirmations Scheduled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
```

How can i achieve this by using the same alarm receiver class and using functions ? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your `PendingIntent` unique. At the moment, both of your calls to `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()` return the same `PendingIntent`.

Change this:

```
PendingIntent pendingintent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

to this:

```
PendingIntent pendingintent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Providing the `id` parameter will make the `PendingIntent` unique.